# Filename incorrect in save dialog - Firefox

Tags: php, header, download

I am redirecting to an image with a Location header from PHP, and in firefox when you view the image and right click to save it prompts to save with the name of the PHP redirect script, not the name of the image. This behaviour is not present in the other browsers.

Here is the code of the file:

```
<?php
header("Location: foo.jpg");
```

Is there anyway to get firefox to use the correct name when a user opens the save dialog?

Comment: Word of advice: many SOers will pass right over questions like this that are a wall of text.  Consider rewriting it to make it more readable, succinct.

Comment: You can use <?php print("<script>window.location='image.jpg';</script>"); ?> instead of header. it support all browser.

Answer (score 0):

jewlhuq's suggestion to bypass php altogether works.

```
<?php print("<script>window.location='image.jpg';</script>"); ?>
```

Using php to read the file's contents and dump those to the browser with the proper headers including the following

```
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="desired-filename.jpg"');
```

also works.

Which is better depends on your application. I used the first for the problem listed above, in another application I needed to serve an image with a different file name than the one it is actually saved with, for that I needed the latter.